# Are complements of generalized eigenspaces $T$-invariant?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, invariant-subspace

Let $T$ be a linear operator of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over the field $F$. Let's assume that $T$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$. Let $K_\lambda$ be the generalized eigenspace of $T$ associated to $\lambda$ and let $W$ be the complement of $K_\lambda$ in $V$ obtained by extending any basis of $K_\lambda$ to a basis of $V$, that is, $V=K_\lambda\oplus W$.

Is $W$ $T$-invariant?

Comment: Not necessarily, because you can make very bad choice of basis (e.g., $T=\operatorname{diag}(1,0)$, $K_0=\langle e_2\rangle$ and you can choose any other line as $W$, but only $\langle e_1\rangle$ is $T$-invariant.